# Grammar behind "a length of 2 meters"

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-article

I believe that

> The length of [something] is 2 meters.

is basically equivalent to

> [Something] has **a** length of 2 meters.

where the following is invalid:

> [Something] has **the** length of 2 meters.

I'm curious about the grammar behind it. Is it

> [Something] has **a** length (that is) of 2 meters.

?

Also, are the following sentences related to the examples above? Are they valid?

> The function `f` has **a** form of `f(x) = x^2`.
>
> The expression has **a** form of `x^2`.

Comment: This site is about English language, not computational linguistics.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for your comment, but I don't think this post has anything to do with computational linguistics. I'm just asking about English grammar.

Comment: Why do you think that *something has the length of two meters* is invalid?

Comment: @FeliniusRex I'm not very sure, but most of the examples I've seen so far used "a"/"an". Grammarly suggests replacing "the" with "a". Also, if my current understanding that "that is" before "of" is omitted is correct, then the phrase "the length that is of 2 meters" feels ungrammatical.